# What are current trends/questions in algebraic logic?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, soft-question, ho.history-overview

What are current trends/questions in algebraic logic? I mean the research developed by Paul Halmos.

Could anyone give some references for the overview of its history? Any overview of its application to computer science and computability theory is welcome.

Comment: What are you actually asking? If algebraic logic is still active? If algebraic logic is finding applications to other areas of logic at the cutting edge?

Comment: @NoahS I mean algebraic logic is still active,I will edit the post,thank you

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.math-inst.hu/pub/algebraic-logic/handbook.pdf. I don't know when it's from, but it cites papers from 1997, so it's pretty recent. I think the answer is basically "yes," so a more detailed question - maybe along the lines of, "What are current trends/questions in algebraic logic?" - would be better for MO.

Comment: Let me just say that I would be very interested in seeing answers to a question about what algebraic logic is doing these days; it's not a field I know anything about, but it sounds fascinating.

Comment: @NoahS,but the post has been downvoted to have been closed,I am very interested in seeing answers too.Maybe you can ask a similiar question in your way that you think is appropriate

Comment: You can edit this question, and then it may be reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran across this today, and was reminded of this question: I think the article "[Algebraic logic, Where does it stand today?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3396712)" by T. S. Ahmed addresses your question.

Comment: Excellent,and very interesting.Thank you, Noah.

Comment: It seems to be paywalled. Can someone provide a summary?

Comment: @gigabytes Fixed, belatedly!